# How to assign index of the collection to property

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have following linq query `productionMachines.OrderBy(x => x.TimeDone).ToList();`
Now I want to assign to some property `X`, index of it's location in the collection.
Like the first productionMachines will receive `X` equals 1 secound 2 and etc...

Example productionMachines have 5 entries.
productionMachine[0].X  will have 1
..
..
..
productionMachine[4].X will have 5

Comment: Can you please clarify your problem a little more. I read your question 3 times now and still got now clue what you want to do... :)

Comment: you probably want to use something like `.Select((row, index) => new {row.X = index})`

Comment: @oleksii well  it would be index+1 because OP wants index to start at 1!

Answer (score 4):

Use the other form of select

```
productionsMachines.OrderBy(x => x.TimeDone)
                                  .Select( (x,i) =>
                                        { 
                                          x.Property = i+1;
                                          return x;
                                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int index= 1;

productionMachines
    .OrderBy(p => p.TimeDone)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(p2 => 
        {
            p2.X = index++;
        }
    );
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that the collection will be iterated twice.  Once for `ToList()` and then once for ForEach

Comment: Thank you @BobVale for clarification. I never thought about that before. Now I should change some of code my projects. :)